# Own asterisk module (SIP logger)

Tags: c++, linux, asterisk

Anybody know how to write module which collect **SIP header data** from Asterisk. 
I found small sample how to write CDR collector, need very close to this module but which get **SIP header**

Exactly I need to collect and parse all data between 
*<--- SIP read from UDP:XXX.XX.XX.XX:6060 --->*
and 
*<------------->*

P.S.
Is possible to get this data in realtime from AGI ? Or I must to write own asterisk module ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest ways do that

1) setup kamailio/opensips instead of asterisk and do sip_trace module config

2) use tcpdump and just capture all packets

Asterisk not designed to provide such info.

No, you can't use AGI for that. No,you can't create module which will capture that.

If you still want do it in asterisk you can

1) enable debug, parse all that in debug file or create logger module for example to database.

2) patch chan_sip.c to store that info in variable, patch your dialplan to save that variable.